# Multiple choice quiz game

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

Im trying to create multiple choice quiz game for kids for my assignment purpose. This quiz has 30 questions all together. The questions are generated randomly. My problem here is the question are being repeated and the game doesn’t end once the questions is out of stock. What should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on what you need. The most straightforward solution (at least if I understood the problem correctly) will be like:

- use two arrays (or lists, whatever) with all possible questions (lets call them `_source` and `_current`)
- at the beginning of the game make sure that `_current` contains all the questions from the `_source`
- select your random question from the `_current` and **REMOVE** it from the `_current`
- if `_current` has no objects - your quiz is ended

In such a case, there will be no situation when questions can be repeated during a single session.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is, have a variable storing the number of questions you have. You said you have 30, so we will work with that. Every time a question is displayed remove 1 from that count. Eg

```
public int Questions;
void Start()
{
  Questions = 30;
}
public void GenerateQuestion()
{
  if(Questions >= 1)
  {
    //Generate your question
  }
  else
  {
    //end game
  }
}
```

Comment: hi, i did as you mentioned and my question is not displaying in the play area. i heve two script which is question generate and question display. im not sure in which script i should attach it and where i should attach it. can you help me with that please.

Comment: Sorry for late response. And the many edits xD. So this sounds like an issue with how you are displaying your questions. In Unity add a UI Text element and call it "Questions" this will display your questions. In the code have `using UnityEngine.UI;` at the top by the others. Then add this `public Text Questions;` back in Unity, create an empty GamObject called "QuestionManager". Add his script to it. Drag and drop the Questions text into the section in the Inspector.

Comment: In my previous code I sent, I said `//Generate your qestions` . Once you have gotten your radom question using whatever method your using, do `Questions.text = //Question;` to assign it. (Replace `//Question ` with the question your generating). Then in the `void Update()` have a way to call this. So maybe after they click the answer for the previous question, do `GenerateQuestion()` this will call the function again.

Comment: When I get home, I'll create an example project and send it to you. With scripts you can use or create your own with :)